# How to remove a data on Angular2 with Firebase implementation?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My dependencies;

```
"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

I have JSON structure on Firebase like;

```
---------0
------------belt: "black"
------------name: "Shaun"
---------1
------------belt: "black"
------------name: "Yoshi"
---------2
------------belt: "red"
------------name: "Ryu"
---------3
------------belt: "purple"
------------name: "Crystal"
------- -Kfc5VqNdnBGS12kIHW0
------------belt: "red"
------------name: "burçak"
------- -Kfc95-192ywFhKJ10BS
------------belt: "yellow"
------------name: "burak"
```

and I have a client-side view like;

[image]

and I want to delete item which I click its delete button but I don't know how to write that code.

I have a little method named 'fbRemoveData' but this method remove all database as expected because I couldn't specify the code and don't know how to.

```
  fbRemoveData(){
    firebase.database().ref('/').remove();
  }
```

In HTML view;

```
<div (click)="fbRemoveData()" [attr.data-name]="ninja.name">delete</div>
```

I'd be appreciated if you would help me through this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On click of the delete button pass the object as

```
<button (click)="deleteClient(item)"> delete</button>

deleteClient(item){
  this.data.splice(this.data.findIndex(item),1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't delete the item from Firebase, I suppose. What I look for is a detailed and specified example of Firebase's remove method.

Comment: My code deleted whole database on Firebase. What I wanted is just to delete the item I click on, not whole database.

Comment: I think you can combine both my answer and the below one to achieve your requirement

Answer (score 0):

When you receive an object from the databe, you also receive its key.
You can then remove a specific object from the database like this:

```
<button (click)="deleteNinja(ninja)">delete</button>
```

---

```
private deleteNinja(ninja: any){
  this.angularFire.database.list('/ninja').remove(ninja.$key);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I wonder what is the ninja of '.list('/ninja)' is? There is no object on JSON starting with 'ninja'. Sorry if my question is too stupid :D But I need to understand the solution properly.

Comment: If your list is at the root of your database, you should probably replace `'/ninja'` by `'/'`.

Comment: There is nothing like Object.$key . It returns 'undefined' on console log. Maybe that is something occured because of my versions of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Ploppy's answer should fix it as long as there is a key. If this is how your data looks on Firebase there doesn't seem to be a key. You should add each ninja item to the database using `this.angularFire.database.list(ninja).push` This way each item will have a key.

Firebase data shouldn't look like this. There should be a key with each object:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Shaun",
    "belt":"black"
  },{
    "name": "Yoshi",
    "belt": "black"
  },{
    "name": "Ryu",
    "belt": "red"
  },{
    "name": "Crystal",
    "belt": "purple"
  }
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed the structure of my JSON displayed on Firebase and I know I need to get those keys such as '0,1 or -Kfc5VqNdnBGS12kIHW0' but I couldn't. I tried to use Plopp's answer but it throws an error saying 'database.list() is not a method' . So I still couldn't get the keys of my JSON.